# SQL: how to replace foreign key column with data from referenced table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 tables, let's call 'm Table-A and Table-B. Table-A contains a FK referencing Table-B. I don't need Table-B anymore, but I do need to keep 1 column from Table-B. So, I want to replace all foreign-keys in Table-A with the data from a single column in the referenced row in Table-B. So I'm wondering, is there a SQL query I can use to perform that action?

It's just a simple sqlite database, if that matters.

To make a bit more clear, here's an 'illustrated' example:

Current situation:

```
TABLE-A:
ID    COL1    COL2    COL3(FK)
-------------------------------
1     text    text    13
2     text    text    14

TABLE-B:
ID    COL4    COL5    COL6
-------------------------------
13    rice    sushi   pizza
14    pasta   fries   chips
```

Wanted situation:

```
TABLE-A:
ID    COL1    COL2    COL3
-------------------------------
1     text    text    pizza
2     text    text    chips
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's called `JOIN`.

```
select
    a.id,
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col6 col3
from tablea a join tableb b
on a.col3 = b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate that :) However, using a JOIN like that is just to display the data. I want to actually move the data in the database.

Comment: I don't know why you'd wanna do that but one way is the create a new table and insert output of this join query in the that table

Comment: *facepalm* Why did I never thought about just creating a new table to replace the other 2... Ah well, I'll see what I can come up with.

Regarding why I want to do that, to keep a long story short: the database is being used for a tiny website, the logic behind the website has changed and part of the data now comes from an external API so it doesn't need to be stored locally anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If is just a query, GurV's answer is good.
If it's something you will use a lot, then i suggest to create a view :

```
CREATE VIEW tablec AS
SELECT a.id, a.col1, a.col2, b.col6 AS col3
FROM tablea a, tableb b
WHERE a.col3 = b.id
```

(sorry, i'm an oldschool SQL developper :))

And now just use :

```
SELECT * FROM tablec
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). As I said to GurV, I don't want to display the data, I want to actually move the data in the database. I guess that wasn't really clear in my question...

He suggested I could just create a third database based on the data from the JOIN instead of moving stuff around. That I never thought about that option.... Ah well, I guess I'll get back to crafting the query...